# make no selections while dragging a window

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a div that sits above the other html elements and I have enabled ngDraggable on that div.  While the div is being dragged, I'm attempting to keep the cursor at 'move' and have nothing in the interface be selected or changed.  The user is simply moving the div to a new location so they can see what's under it.

The code I have so far almost works, but when the cursor is dragged over a textarea it looses the move pointer, gets the text select cursor, and text in the text area is selected.

```
  whileDragging(e){
    let guidedWindow = document.getElementById("theGuidedWindow");
    guidedWindow.classList.add("noTransitions");
    document.body.className = 'noSelect'; //-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: move;
    if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble=true;
    e.returnValue=false;
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: What do you have set for the class `noSelect` (in terms of CSS)? You should be able to set the pointer to a static pointer and prevent selecting.

Comment: its -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: move;  works, but not when dragged over a textarea.

Comment: What if you set `pointer-events: none;`?

Comment: Also, you would want to set it in all elements, not just the body. So `.noSelect, .noSelect *`